# Platform Events and Transaction

Tags: integration, platform-event

I want to trigger an Event from Apex Trigger, but since Platform event cannot be rollbacked, is there a way to publish it only when the transaction is successfull?

Answer (score 6):

Based on some sleuthing by [@danielballinger](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/102/daniel-ballinger) I believe that becomes an option in Summer 19 (#safeharbor and all that)

PreRelease Orgs are now available if you want to check it out for yourself, or you can wait for Sandbox upgrades to start

[image: Platform Event Publish Changes]